# Mesh modification

Tags: mesh

When I add a UV sphere and try to modify the segments, rings, radius or any other changes the drop down menu just disappear and I'm left with 32 segments and 16 rings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this menu only appears when an pbject is newly added. You cannot (unfortunately) reopen it later.

Comment: Hello :). If the menu disappears, you can use *F9 key* to bring it up.

Comment: As soon as I click on the menu it disappears. I was able to use the modeling tab and that worked for the sphere. However, I added a cylinder and the menu just disappears.